# Получение картинок с сайта

Tags: java, android-studio

Делаю программу для расписания и возникла проблема.

Можно ли использовать картинки с интернета, т.е. подгружать их с помощью JSON? Или это делается как-то по другому? Что вообще для этого нужно использовать?

Comment: "Надеюсь вы поняли суть моего вопроса."- `нет`, "Буду ждать помощи." - `помощи в чем?`

Comment: куда вы собираетесь подгружать эти изображения? это веб-приложение? десктоп-приложение?.. покажите что у вас уже есть и куда вы собираетесь это выводить или Ваши попытки их вывести если таковые имелись

Comment: Это Android приложение.У меня есть активити с Shared Preference. я хочу сделать аналог стены в контакте только для учебного заведения. то есть расписание я буду скачивать с оф сайта учебного заведения в ImageView,но проблема в том, что я не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: в тексте вопроса, пожалуйста всё это изложите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подргузки изображений используйте [эту](http://square.github.io/picasso/) библиотеку. По ссылке все детально рассписано как ей пользоваться.

Добавьте зависимость build.gradle файл.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

И вот пример кода который по ссылке загружает картинку и вставляет в ImageView:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```